# How to print class attribute from array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, class, element, record

Say I have a class like so

```
class Date 
    attr_accessor :day, :month, :year
end
```

And I create 3 records for it, and add each to an array.

```
class Date 
    attr_accessor :day, :month, :year
end

date = Date.new()
date.day = 31
date.month = 12
date.year = 2019
array = []
array << date

date = Date.new()
date.day = 30
date.month = 2
date.year = 2014
array << date

date = Date.new()
date.day = 23
date.month = 1
date.year = 2012
array << date
```

If I wanted puts date.day (or every attribute) from the third record/third element of the array specifically, how would I access it (if I want to print it, or access it from a different function/procedure when specific user input is required)? Something like puts array[2] obviously doesn't work.

Comment: The name `Date` is a really bad choice as its already a part of the Ruby standard library.

Comment: Ah ok. Is there a way to see beforehand what's part of Ruby's standard library/a way to check for it?

Comment: well that's a bit tricky - `Date` isn't actually defined until you require it. There are several list of reserved words in Ruby but I guess the only real way to check for name collision is to search the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array[2]` would return the third element from the array. When you want to call `day` then you can write

```
puts array[2].day
```

If you want to print the day of all elements in the array you might want to do:

```
array.each do |element|
  puts element.day
end
```